# How to reformat multiple branches at once in Git?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Let's suppose I've got a branch structure in Git that looks like `master -> A -> B`. That is, `A` contains commits on top of `master` and `B` contains commits on top of `A`.

I would like to reformat `A`, without resulting in a massive set of conflicts in `B` that will need to be resolved by hand. If I'm not mistaken, I could do this with [git filter-branch](https://medium.com/@elliotchance/reformatting-your-codebase-with-git-filter-branch-21feded7c423), except I don't want anything in `master` to change. (I.e. I don't want to invalidate all the public Git commit ID in the project.)

Is there a way to `git filter-branch` on just `A` and `B` (or just as good for my purpose, all of the branches in the repo *except* `master`)?

Edit: In particular, is it sufficient to do `git filter-branch ... A B`? Will this avoid touching `master` and keep `A` and `B` consistent with each other (i.e. rewrite the common commits between `A` and `B` to the same commit IDs and not allow them to be duplicated, or something like that).

Comment: Do you mean that your branch structure looks like ‘master <- A <- B‘? As in B was branched from A, and A was branched from master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right general idea here (of how to use filter-branch), but the wrong syntax.  To get `git filter-branch` to copy (and filter) commits that are reachable from both names `A` and `B` but not to copy+filter commits that are reachable from `master`, use the syntax:

```
git filter-branch <options> -- ^master A B
```

What we're doing here, with the `git rev-list` arguments `^master A B`, is telling Git: *Find all commits reachable from either `A` or `B`, excluding all commits reachable from `master`*.  So if the commit chains go:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
            \
             o--o--o   <-- A
                    \
                     o--o   <-- B
```

for instance, this selects the middle and bottom row commits.  It would even with `^master B` or `master..B`, as in [phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58157395/1256452), but this is better for two reasons.  First, it would still select all middle-row commits with:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
            \
             o--o--o   <-- A
                 \
                  o--o   <-- B
```

(although this is presumably not your structure).  Second, *after* copying (and filtering) the specified commits such that you wind up with:

```
                     o--o   <-- [filtered copy of commit to which B points]
                    /
             o--o--o   [filtered copy of commit to which A points]
            /
...--o--o--o   <-- master
            \
             o--o--o   <-- A
                    \
                     o--o   <-- B
```

the filter-branch command will move all of what [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) calls *positive references*.  A positive reference is one that does not have a negation in front of it: in this case, `A` and `B`, but not `master`, as `master` is written `^master` and is therefore a negative reference.

Hence this won't touch `master` (not that it would anyway—its commit did not get copied) but *will* yank the names `A` and `B` over so that they point to the copied commits.

Note that if you don't want changes made to the snapshots in the two (in this example) `B`-only commits, it is up to you to write a clever filter that does that.  (Or to use a filter that makes no tree changes, but by "reformat" I assume you want to use `--tree-filter` and something like `clang-format` on the *snapshots* in each of the various `A` commits.  It's probably more sensible to go ahead and make the same formatting changes to the various `B` commits as well.)

Answer (score 0):

> git filter-branch ... A B

No, this will process branches A and B back to the root commit. I'd go this way:

```
A_behind_B=`git rev-list --count A..B`
git filter-branch ... master..B # or ^master B
git checkout A
git reset --hard B~$A_behind_B
```

Count by how many commits A is behind B. Run `filter-branch` on commits from `master` to B. Reset A to be that commits behind the new B.